# Что лучше использовать Result или Exception

Tags: c#, исключения, валидация

Есть бизнес класс, который выполняет какую-то единицу работы:

```
class EmployeeCalculator
{
    public Pay CalculatePay(Employee employee)
    {
        //Do somthing
    }
}
```

По каким-то причинам выполнение метода CalculatePay может завершиться с ошибкой.
Собственно вопрос: как лучше будет передать ошибку ? Можно сделать какой-нибудь класс типа:

```
public class PayResult
{
    public Pay Pay { get; set; }
    public bool IsError { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

И возвращать его из метода CalculatePay, а на вызывающей стороне проверять IsError.
Либо из метода CalculatePay бросить исключение, и так же на вызывающей стороне ловить его. Если бросать исключение то на каком уровне его ловить (предположим что наше приложение использует MVC) ? На уровне контроллеров и там уже перерабатывать и выдавать сообщения на UI или это может быть отдельный слой обработки ошибок между контроллером и бизнес логикой ?

PS. Буду благодарен любой информации по вопросу (ваши мысли, статьи, книги).

Comment: Исключение наверно будет лучше. И как сами заметили даже появляется выбор где его словить. Вообще исключения настойчиво предлагают считать частью контракта метода. Такой альтернативный результат.

Comment: Первый вариант предпочтительнее, ошибка обработанная сервером всегда лучше, чем ошибка обработанная клиентом

Comment: *на каком уровне его ловить* - в том и достоинство исключений, что ловить их можно на любом уровне выше. А код ошибки нужно обрабатывать по месту (или вручную протаскивать наверх).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все зависит от причины, по которой не удалось посчитать Pay.

Если это действительно исключительная ситуация - например, невалидные данные для расчета - то нужно бросать исключение.

Если это ожидаемая ситуация - например, Employee ничего не заработал - то стоит возвращать или Pay с 0 (возможно, как преодпределенный экземпляр Pay.None), или возвращать null - если ваш клиентский код готов этот null обработать.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше PayResult, если результат не посчитан значит PayResult.Pay = null, если клиенту нужны подробности то пусть смотрит PayResult.ErrorMessage. Исключения нужны когда системный сбой, неправильные аргументы функции когда продолжить работу невозможно, а у вас возврат результата которого можно и не получить - вполне штатная ситуация.

Answer (score 2):

Если ошибка возникает очень редко (является **исключительной** ситуацией), то выкидывать исключение.

Если ошибка - почти норма, возникает часто, то можно возвращать код ошибки.

Распространённый подход - иметь два метода: один выкидывает исключение, другой, с префиксом `Try` возвращает булево значение, сигналирующее об успешности операции. Например:

```
int.Parse      - int.TryParse
DateTime.Parse - DateTime.TryParse
```

и другие.